# How do we use hook for Feathersjs + Apollo v2?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, feathersjs

Having problem setting up hook for Feathersjs + Apollo v2. Main reason needing it is for authorization.

```
src/services/graphql/graphql.service.js:65
  service.hooks(hooks);
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hooks' of undefined
```

Following is my codes for setting up Apollo v2 in Feathersjs service. Since it does not carry a model, I'm not sure what's the correct way to set up the hook.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const hooks = require('./graphql.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {

  const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
      hello: String
    }
  `;

  const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      hello: () => 'hello world'
    }
  };

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: typeDefs,
    resolvers: resolvers,
    context: ({req, res}) => ({
      provider: req.feathers.provider,
      headers: req.feathers.headers,
      token: req.headers['auth-token']
    }),
    playground: {
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:3030/graphql',
      settings: {
        'editor.theme': 'light'
      }
    }
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  // app.use('/graphql', createService);

  const service = app.service('graphql');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Comment: Interesting - ok, `server.applyMiddleware` calls `app.use` under the covers.  Can you show how you're creating your initial `app` object and how you're registering this service?

Comment: It's a fresh feathersjs project. So initial `app` calling `const services = require('./services');` and services index.js calling  `const graphql = require('./graphql/graphql.service.js');`, which is the sample up there.

Comment: so, app is `const app = express(feathers());`?

Comment: Yup, `const app = express(feathers());` followed by app.use and app.configure, eg. `app.configure(services);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, feathers' REST support doesn't really do what you want.

If you pass a Feathers service to `app.use` it will be available as part of the ecosystem of hooks etc.  If you just pass in Express services (or do that indirectly, as `applyMiddleware` does) then Feathers will skip over it.  It's registered with Express, but it's not in the list of Feathers services in `app.services`.

You can register services with Feathers that chain both Express-type middleware and Feathers services, like:

```
app.use('/thing',
  (req, res, next) => {
     // does something
     next();
  },
  {
    get(id, params) {
      // feathers stuff
    }
  }
);
```

at which point the entire service IS available to the Feathers ecosystem, hooks, etc.

What you might be able to do is something like:

```
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: 'graphql' });
  app.use('graphql', {
    create(data, params) {
    },
    get(id, params) {
    },
    find(params) {
    },
    update(id, data, params) {
    },
    patch(id, data, params) {
    },
    delete(id, params) {
    }
  }); 
  app.service('graphql').hooks(hooks);
```

to chain (no-op) services AFTER the `/graphql` stuff is set up, but I'm not sure you won't have to put some logic into those services to munge the data correctly.  Remember that feathers services assume JSON etc.

Your other choice is to validate your authorization token (I assume a JWT from authentication-jwt?) in Express middleware for the graphql stuff, and not try to Feather-ize the /graphql service at all.

Comment: What if I want to get the user information (eg. ID) from feathersjs and perform a filtration on the results?

Comment: you can reverse the order, putting the Feathers service stuff first, with an express-style middleware chained afterwards.

Comment: It seems to work, but I can't access graphQL playground anymore due to `  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: 'graphql' });`. Seems to be limitation from apollo, https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1908